# UIlabel gives incorrect float value at runtime

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am assigning a float value to a UIlabel and when the limit exceeds its limit to handle, the value changes and shows me incorrect result.I am using autoresize text with a minimum font text value and truncate tail.
I am making a calculator.If i want a result for 50000x50000 the the result should be 2500000000.0000 but the label shows something like 2499999548.0000

Comment: add your calculated result text code  of your label.

Comment: How about if you use `double` instead of `float`? Float is inaccurate when working with large numbers (see wikipedia). Can you post your code for assigning the value to the label?

Comment: try ((float)50000*50000)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a read of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point... you will find that any number larger than about 10,000 needs to be using a 64 bit float instead of a 32 bit float if you want to have four decimal places.

The `double` data type is a 64 bit float.

Be especially careful of `CGFloat` because that will be 64 bit on an iPhone 5S and 32 bit on an iPhone 5C and any older iPhone.

A 64 bit float is accurate for numbers in the billions. Anything larger than that and you'll want to start working with the `NSDecimalNumber` class. This is probably what you should do for a calculator app.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsdecimalnumber_class/reference/reference.html

Here's a demonstration of why you shouldn't use float or double when you need accuracy:

```
float aFloat = 10000.2;
float bFloat = 10000.0;
NSLog(@"%.15f", aFloat - bFloat); // 0.200195312500000

double aDouble = 10000.2;
double bDouble = 10000.0;
NSLog(@"%.15f", aDouble - bDouble); // 0.200000000000728

NSDecimalNumber *a = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"10000.2"];
NSDecimalNumber *b = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"10000.0"];
NSLog(@"%@", [a decimalNumberBySubtracting:b]); // 0.2
```

It's even worse with really big numbers:

```
float aFloat = 10000000000000000000000.2;
float bFloat = 10000000000000000000000.0;
NSLog(@"%.15f", aFloat - bFloat); // 0.000000000000000

double aDouble = 10000000000000000000000.2;
double bDouble = 10000000000000000000000.0;
NSLog(@"%.15f", aDouble - bDouble); // 0.000000000000000

NSDecimalNumber *a = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"10000000000000000000000.2"];
NSDecimalNumber *b = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"10000000000000000000000.0"];
NSLog(@"%@", [a decimalNumberBySubtracting:b]); // 0.2
```

Comment: It is giving me correct results till 5000000x1000000 = 5000000000000 but if i multiply this result again with 10 then the answer is coming out to be 49,999,999,139,840.00

Comment: @Yieshu Floating point values are never "correct", it's impossible for a float to store a precise value. As the number gets larger, they get less precise. Even 5 * 5 will give you an incorrect float if you examine the value to 10 or 20 decimal places. With really large values, the accuracy becomes so bad the data format becomes totally useless.

Comment: @Yieshu see my updated answer to demonstrate float inaccuracies. you should read up on the wikipedia page I linked to understand why it's doing that. Note that double doesn't solve the problem perfectly, it just means you need larger values to run into the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display your calculation then use  *(Here You need to cast **float**.)*

```
float mycalculation = (float)50000*50000;
yourLableName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", mycalculation ];
```

I use above code it working properly for me.

Comment: Its fine till here but if we again multiply tetsingD with 1000 then the result will be like 499999999584.0000.How to get it accurate as 500000000000.00

Comment: @Yieshu - then you need to change float to double such like .. double mycalculation = (double)50000*50000*1000;

Comment: I did this but there is no effect on the answer.I am doing as double result = ((double)result1 * (double)[string floatvalue]);

Answer (score 0):

Try This, Its working .....

Ask me if any query...

```
NSString *a = @"50000";
NSString *b = @"50000";
float ValueA = [a floatValue]; //instead of "a" you can pass Textfield1.text
float ValueB = [b floatValue]; //instead of "b" you can pass Textfield2.text

NSLog(@"%@",[self getStringFromFloat:ValueA*ValueB]);

-(NSString *)getStringFromFloat:(float)yourFloatValue
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Value =%.4f",yourFloatValue];
}
```

Comment: I am doing it this way even then i am not getting the required results

Comment: Tell me your actual case , is you have two string or float values for multiplication?

Answer (score 0):

```
float num;
num = 50000.0f * 50000.0f;
Lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",num];
```

Its work for me perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

Type define your result as well and preferably in such cases use double than just float

These two lines on code will work..

```
 double num = (double)50000*50000;
 label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f",num];
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding 'f' to the end of the value should do the trick.  Unlike 5.0 , 5.0f gives you the literal value of a float.

Try `50000.0f x 50000.0f`